# Rails 4 image_tag not loading Image from Assets

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, image, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have placed all my assets in the following folders

```
app/assets/images/admin/*  <---- Admin Template
app/assets/images/default/* <----- Frontend Template
```

Now when i am trying to use the following code

```
<%= link_to image_tag('default/user-photo-medium-jpg', :class => 'media-object img-circle', :style => 'width: 64px; height: 64px;'), '#' %>
```

It generated the following code and the image does not load in the Development Environment.

```
<a href="#"><img style="width: 64px; height: 64px;" src="/images/default/user-photo-medium-jpg" class="media-object img-circle" alt="User photo medium jpg"></a>
```

Comment: I guess a forward slash will do the trick `image_tag('/default/user-photo-medium-jpg')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image source points to "/images/default/user-photo-medium-jpg". Are you sure that the image has correct ending (.jpg) and not -jpg?

Comment: this is craziness :( it was *-*